# Connect 4.1 speakers to Acer V3-571G with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: sound, jack

I have the Acer Aspire V3-571G that has only 2 audio jack: 1 for headphone and 1 for microphone.

Can I connect my Creative 4.1 speakers and have sound in all 5 channels?

The problem is that speakers have a double green/black wire for front/rear channel but PC has only 1 jack. Is it possible to use microphone jack to export sound instead of import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Some* sound cards support a 2.1 setup with headphone/mic but I've only ever seen that once, on a very high-end laptop. That was also with a proprietary Windows driver. I've no idea if that would ever support Linux. 4.1 in this vein will be impossible. 4.1 will require at least three jacks.

The solution is simple: a cheapy 5.1 USB soundcard dongle. The Zalman ZM-RSSC, for example, can be bought for under $10. It's on lead to plug in and you're away.